# Using findOne with sequelize-typescript returns undefined data

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I try to use sequelize-tyscript to read data from a little sqlight-db.If I call findOne I got an instance of my model, but if I try to read properties I always get undefined.

My Model:

```
import {Table, Column, Model, PrimaryKey} from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table
export class ApiKeys extends Model<ApiKeys>{

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    key: string;

    @Column
    role: string;

}
```

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [apikeys] (
   [KEY] VARCHAR(36)  NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [ROLE] NVARCHAR(20)  NULL
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont see any find query in code. Can you please add that?

Answer (score 0):

Column-property-mapping is casesensitive. That was my problem!